# Number theory contradiction

Tags: number-theory

I was solving this question

> How many pairs of integers $(a,b)$ that satisfies the following conditions:
>
> 1. $1\le a,b\le 42$
> 2. $a^9\equiv b^7\pmod{43}$

and I ran into a contradiction:

We know by Fermat's Little Theorem that $a^{42} \equiv 1 \pmod{43}$ and $b^{42} \equiv 1 \pmod{43}$. Thus, we make the given condition in the problem equivalent to $a^{54} \equiv b^{42} \equiv 1 \pmod{43}$. Then, $a^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod{43}$.

I don't see the problem in my reasoning here. We have $a^{54} \equiv 1 \pmod{43}$ is equivalent to saying $a^9\equiv b^7\pmod{43}$ since $43$ is prime, but $6^{54} \equiv 1 \pmod{43}$ while $6^9 \equiv 1 \pmod{43}$ and $6^9 \equiv b^7 \pmod{43}$ isn't true for all $b$ as $a^{54} \equiv 1 \pmod{43}$ suggests. So how is it not equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

Your two conditions imply $a^{54}\equiv1\pmod{43}$, but not the other way round. You raised to the $6$th power in a step, but this step is not reversible. For example, it's obvious that $(-1)^6=1^6$ does not imply $-1=1$.

Comment: How is that not reversible if we can divide since any number between $1$ and $42$ is relatively prime to $43$?

Comment: @user19405892 If my interpretation of what you say is correct - you hope that raising to a power is fine because $ab\equiv ac\pmod{43}$ is equivalent to $b\equiv c\pmod{43}$ given $a\not\equiv0\pmod{43}$. This is not actually how powers work though - taking a simpler example, $a^2\equiv b^2\pmod{43}$ does not imply $a\equiv b\pmod{43}$. You cannot use the division property in this case because you have not multiplied by the same thing on both sides.

Comment: In terms of solving this question, will using Fermat's Little Theorem help?

Comment: @user19405892 Well you've certainly found a necessary condition in that $a^{12}\equiv1\pmod{43}$. That already reasonably limits the possibilities. Still, I have not thought about how to answer the problem, I have only answered the question stated above - by explaining why there isn't a contradiction.

Comment: I have shown that  condition two is equivalent to $a^3 b^7 \equiv 1 \pmod{43}$. Is there a way to continue from here?

Answer (score 2):

The implication

$$x\equiv y\implies x^n\equiv y^n$$

is *always* true, for any modulus and any integer $n$.  But the *converse*, $x^n\equiv y^n\implies x\equiv y$, is **not** true in general.  So there is no logical basis for saying that $a^9\equiv b^7$ mod $43$ is "equivalent" to $a^{54}\equiv b^{42}$ mod $43$.

Answer (score 0):

3 is a cyclical generator for $Z_{43}$
Every number in between 1 and 42 can be expressed as $3^n$

$a= 3^n, b = 3^m\\
a^9 \equiv 3^{9n} \mod 43\\
b^7 \equiv 3^{7m} \mod 43$

the only numbers that overlap are $3^{21} \equiv 42$ and $3^{42} \equiv 1.$

$a^9\equiv b^7\equiv 1 \mod 43$

$a = 1, 4, 16,21, 41,35, 11,$ and $b = 1,6,36.$ or

$a^9\equiv b^7\equiv 42 \mod 43$

$a = 42, 39, 27,22, 2,8, 32,$ and $b = 42, 37,7.$